# Python logging with Supervisor

Tags: python, logging, supervisord

I'm currently using supervisor to monit and daemonize some python scripts easily. However, it seems that supervisor won't log properly. 
The scripts I'm executing is as simple as this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pushybullet as pb
import sys, time, logging

# INIT LOGGING
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s @%(name)s [%(levelname)s]:    %(message)s', level = logging.DEBUG)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
            logging.info('Custom service started')
            while True:
                    #here for the sake of example, actually doing real stuff here
                    time.sleep(2)
    finally:
            logging.info('Custom service stopped')
```

And here is the corresponding conf file :

```
[program:myscript]
directory=/home/pi/Documents/Scripts_py
command=python -u myscript.py
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

So I've tested many things based on many researched on google.
Replacing logging lines by print and then flushing stdout indeeds works; same with -u option to launche the script. But print is not adequate for my needs, Python's logging module is. So I tried to flush after each logging line, and to launch the script in unbuffered mod, but nothing appears!

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you tried specifying the log file you want in your conf file?
For example: stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log

Comment: Isn't that for specifying where we want supervisor to output it's own log of the program? If yes, it won't help me as the problem I'm facing is that my script's log is not captured by supervisor at all

Comment: Okay I gave it a try and it's the solution, thank you!

Comment: Yes, that is correct (regarding file access permissions), even though you can specify the uid in your supervisor conf file:

user=youruser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Pedro Rodrigues, I've found. For anyone struggling like me, well just know that you just create a fileHandler like this :

```
fh = logging.FileHandler('/var/log/supervisor/your_program_name.log')
```

And add to your program conf file :

```
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/%(program_name)s.log
```

The scripts will write in the log, then read by supervisor, visible on the web interface. One issue it might create is a permission denied if you try to start your script without supervisor.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your shebang as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S python -u
```

This will deactivate Python buffering to stdout/stderr.