# why the timestamp comparison in 'if' statement not working as per the logic applied in my python program?

Tags: python, automation, python-3.6

On my prod server, I will be executing a python prog through a cron tab that'll monitor a cloud location and if there is any new file available, it will be pulled and install on the server from where the python prog is running. However, there are possibilities that the cloud repo might not get the new file for days. So, in that case, the last updated file would remain the latest file for the python program until a new file comes. So, one way is to keep comparing the timestamp of a file with some flag in the code, i.e. if the timestamp of a Debian file doesn't change then the python program compares the timestamp of a file with the flag and then exit/pass, or else execute the business logic. Below is the code snippet that I am trying to work with:

```
import os 
import subprocess 
import glob 

src_path = glob.iglob('path_to/*.deb')
trgt_path = '<Path>' 

try:
    for i in src_path:
        ltst_file = max(i, key=os.path.getmtime)
        time_stamp = os.path.getmtime(ltst_file)
        flag = 0
        while True:
            if flag == time_stamp:
                pass
            else:
                subprocess.Popen(['cp', '-r', ltst_file, trgt_path])
                flag = time_stamp
                break
except (ValueError, Exception, FileNotFoundError) as foo:
    print("Program couldn't bring the file from ab20", foo)
```

1) First time program will always go to the "else" block because the value of the flag and the time_stamp would be different.However, it should go to "if" block the 2nd time if the source location doesn't get updated with any new file. But it never goes to the "if" block in my case.

2)To further troubleshoot I ran the prog without 'break'. This time it again went to the 'else' block and updated the target location with the same file that came to the source location couple of days back, but for a change, it went to the "if" block after doing it and remains there forever. So, ideally, it fulfills the partial requirement but not completely as it should directly go to the 'if' block and exit/pass instead of going to 'else' block to copy the file to the target location in the first place as the file is same days old. I have used try and except block to catch any error,

3) With the 'break' statement in the program, the code just gives below message.

```
Program couldn't bring the file from ab20 [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'g'
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am not sure what is the logic I am missing on, please suggest.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x20.py", line 7, in <module>
    ltst_file = max(src_path, key=os.path.getmtime)
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

### Adding empty list error:

```
[]
No files found at all.
[]
No files found at all.
[]
No files found at all.
[]
No files found at all.
[]
No files found at all.
[]
No files found at all.
```

I am able to cd to the cloud location through CLI,and can confirm that there are 5 debian files.

### Couple of concerns:

1) Our plan is to execute the code through cron job. So, if my understanding right, then each time cron job executes, the value of "latest_timestamp_processed" will always default to None. So, in case the cloud location is not updated even for couple of hours, then the code will always consider the already available file as latest file, and it would continue working on the same file again and again. Please correct me if I am wrong. Is there anyway, we can address this issue by modifing the existing code somehow? or if you have some alternate suggestion do let me know.

2) I am planning to execute the code in the background and generate logs through python logging module. I have modified the code to use the logging module, as logs are required. So, yes executing the code continuously in the background will generate huge logs, which I can definitely run a cron to delete them at certain interval. This part I just wanted to let you know.

Otherwise, your code is working as desired.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the `max()` function?

Comment: The `break` command pops it out of the loop. And the 'if' block does not do anything to change the loop.

Comment: Not sure about the rest of your logic, but your `max` statement will not work. The first argument to max must be an iterable (`i` is not). I suspect you want `ltst_file = max(src_path, key=os.path.getmtime)`. But that and your `time_stamp =` line will not change in the loop, so they an be moved before the loop.

Comment: I have already tried adding src_path in max(), but I always got a "empty sequence" error, I have updated the main post. That was the main reason I used for loop for adding iterator feature, but  guess it didn't work. So, if you say that the max() function will not work, then please suggest with alternate logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot comment so far - if I understand correctly, you need a script that

- runs endless
- looks periodically for the newest files in the given source path
- if a new file exists that is younger than the last file you've copied,
  then copy that file once, afterwards wait again for newer files

Correct? Here is a suggestion how to solve it. Instead of your copy I've just used a
`print`, it was easier to test. Insert what you need.

```py
import os
import time
import glob

latest_timestamp_processed = None # no one yet

while True:

    source_files = list(glob.iglob('*.deb'))

    if len(source_files) > 0: # only do sth. if there are files

        latest_file = max(source_files, key=os.path.getmtime)
        latest_timestamp = os.path.getmtime(latest_file)

        if (latest_timestamp_processed is None) \
                or (latest_timestamp>latest_timestamp_processed):

                    try:
                        print("Processing latest file '{}'..".format(latest_file))
                        # subprocess.Popen(['cp', '-r', latest_file, target_path])
                        latest_timestamp_processed = latest_timestamp
                    except Exception as exc:
                        print("Errors processing latest file '{}': {}".format(latest_file, exc))
        else:
            print("No newer files found.")
    else:
        print("No files found at all.")

    time.sleep(1) # wait a second (maybe specify more)
```

I've inserted the `time.sleep(1)` in order to preserve CPU power.

In order to test the script, you could run it in one terminal, then open a second terminal and create new (empty) files using

```sh
touch test.deb
```

or if you want to use a specific date in order to simulate too old files

```sh
touch test.deb -d "2019-01-03"
```

Good luck.

Comment: I've placed the `try..except` clause inside the loop because I expect that you need your script kept running in case of errors. You could also exit the while loop on errors if you need to bail out.

Comment: yes , your understanding is correct. I will work on your suggestion and would tell you the result. Thank you for your effort though.

Comment: I worked on it, and the program directly went to the last 'else' block, saying:-- No files found at all. So I used the print statement just after the source_file, and I got empty list. I have updated in the main post.

Comment: Have you tried exactly my code? It worked for me as soon as the first file appears in the **current directory**. Note that I haven't used an input directory in the line `source_files = list(glob.iglob('*.deb'))`. Have you added your correct input directory? And if yes, do the ".deb" files show up if you list them using "ls" from the server where the script is installed?

Comment: Yes, I have used exactly the same code that you have provided, except that I replaced the source_path with my path. I was able to go to the location through CLI and do the ls, I could see 5 debian files there available.

Comment: Ok, then I have no clue. On my laptop the code works and I don't know what is different in your environment. Maybe it would help to edit your question and replace the part "Adding empty list error" with a detailed description: how the script looks like you have now (mine with the added path) and the shell commands you use to see the 5 debian files, what the output is from that comand. There must be some simple problem, if your "ls" shows the files but the listing in the script does not find the files.

Comment: Thank you mcrot, I am working on it and will keep you updated.

Comment: Hello mcrot, the code is now picking the right file, initially there was some environment issues so it gave empty list. Now I need to test this code through cron job and my business logic within 'try' block. Will keep you updated further

Comment: Ok, thanks! Please accept my answer if it turns out during your test that it is working for you. Good luck!

Comment: Hello mcrot, The code runs a charm. But I have two concerns, please let me know if we can tackle it. I have updated the main post with my points

Comment: About your second concern: Just use another handler for your log files, a rotating file handler, which automaticallly starts new log files and deletes older ones. Please have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler) or [at this tutorial](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/02/11/python-how-to-create-rotating-logs/) (it's a bit old, maybe the API changed a bit). You can choose if you want to rotate log files based on size or time.

Comment: About your first concern: The code is meant to run in an endless loop. I did this, because I didn't want to go to far away from your own original idea. If you keep the endless loop, don't use cron but start your script automatically as background service. You can use e.g. [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/index.html) which, once configured correctly, does this for you. If you need to use cron, you have to change the script and save the timestamp elsewhere (e.g. in a file) and reread the timestamp on every run. Since the script is running now, I suggest to try `supervisor` instead. HTH.

Comment: This SO question might also help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224294/python-logging-with-supervisor

Comment: Thank you for your help, now we can conclude the thread. I am going to use the script that is running endlessly, and since we can rotate logs as well as delete them at some time interval , so I guess cron is needless.